# Why should one show that $x$ and $0$ are linearly dependent?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules

In exercise 1 of D&F section 12.1, it's stated:

> Let $M$ be a module over the integral domain $R$. Suppose $x$ is a nonzero torsion element in $M$. Show that $x$ and $0$ are "linearly dependent." Conclude that the rank of $\mathrm{Tor}(M)$ is $0$.

I'm missing the point of why I should show that $x$ and $0$ are linearly dependent. Isn't it obvious that any set containing $0$ is linearly dependent? In order to conclude that the rank of $\mathrm{Tor}(M)$ is $0$, I need to show that *any* nonempty subset of $\mathrm{Tor}(M)$ is linearly dependent and this is immediate from the definition: if $S\subseteq\mathrm{Tor}(M)$ is nonempty, then it contains an element $m$, and there is a nonzero element $r$ of $R$ such that $rm = 0$; since this is a linear combination of elements of $S$ with not all coefficients zero, it follows that $S$ is linearly dependent.

Comment: FYI, this is included in the errata to the book.  See here: http://www.cems.uvm.edu/~rfoote/errata_3rd_edition.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're totally right.  What it should say is to show that the set $\{x\}$ is linearly dependent.  Since a subset of a linearly independent set is linearly independent and $x\in\operatorname{Tor}(M)$ is arbitrary, this shows that no nonempty subset of $\operatorname{Tor}(M)$ is linearly independent.  Of course, this is just a different way of phrasing the argument that you gave.